# How can we clear cache in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am new in angular Js, creating a small project with 5 pages.
I have written some scripts and CSS for the home page, when I click on another page the same CSS and scripts run on that page also.

My problem is I have kept that CSS and scripts on home page only then why another pages inherit that ?

How can I make clear cache ?

Comment: Angular is a single page app (SPA) so the layout is the same for every routes (pages).

Comment: What do you mean another page?Is that html page,aspx page pr php what?As Michelem said angularjs is mostly used in SPA.so it depends what you are exactly trying to do.Please be clear on this.

Comment: This is a php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is used to make [Single Page Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). When you are creating CSS classes, your entire document inherits the classes and their properties.

If you don't want other pages to inherit these CSS properties, you should create CSS class specific to homepage having unique names. Implies, each page will have their own classes with required properties. However that totally defeats the purpose of reusable CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be helpful for you -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Answer (score 0):

if we use css in index or root page , it will inherit from other pages so , you have to write unique css for the index or root page which it does't have other page element style , and include css for other page.

Answer (score -1):

According to css you can use !important in every view you want to change css and to apply in that view. For example:

```
.item {
    border-color: #111 !important; 
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using important as much as possible and unless there is no other possibility, then may be you can use this but not as a first option.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use angular ui router its what i understood can help you tho go with  [this](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router).